# how to config resources sub directory in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I create Spring Boot and set the following values in `application.properties` to configure the location of static resources and JSPs

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

spring.mvc.static-path-pattern: /resources/**
```

below is an example of using a static file which **loaded correctly**

```
<img src="/resources/img/img1.jpg" alt="view">
```

but the code below **does not load**

```
<img src="/resources/img/journal/img1.jpg" alt="not view">
```

The corresponding error is below

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: File [&#47;WEB-INF&#47;views&#47;journal&#47;resources.jsp] not found
```

How do I correctly configure the location of static resources?

Comment: spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**, seems its have :